# "выдержка" vs. "терпение"

Tags: выбор-слова

Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, в чем разница между значением и употреблением слов "выдержка" (как черта характера, а не как фото-термин) и "терпение".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти слова могут значить одно и то же, но в ряде случаев между ними будет явное смысловое различие.

**"Проявить терпение"** - значит показать свою способность стойко и безропотно переносить что-либо, обычно в течение долгого времени.

**"Проявить выдержку"** - значит не потерять самообладания в критической ситуации. Показать хорошую выдержку можно и за несколько секунд.

Словом "терпение" называют как способность терпеть, так и само это действие и состояние. У этих слов разная коннотация. Слово "терпение" ассоциируется с христианскими добродетелями:

> «Антоний затворил дверь и ушел, оставив старца. Но увидев терпение
>   Макария, отворил ему дверь, приветствовал его и сказал: слышав о твоих
>   делах, я давно желал видеть тебя»

Слово "выдержка" новее (скажем, у Даля этого слова нет) и больше ассоциируется с эпохой СССР. Малый академический словарь Института русского языка Академии наук СССР определяет выдержку как "Умение владеть собой; самообладание".

Answer (score 0):

я думаю выдержка это скорее черта характера, а терпение - характеристика процесса терпения. эти слова были бы больше синонимами, если бы слово терпение было заменено, словом терпеливость

Answer (score 0):

`Выдержка` - composure, self-command, self-control, self-possession, self-government, self-mastery, self-restraint, personal coolness, control

`Терпение` - patience, bearing, sufferance, tolerance, endurance

Answer (score -1):

Официальную разницу обьяснить не берусь (тут надо лезть в толковые словари), но
мне кажется, что терпение - это когда тебя обижают, а выдержка - когда провоцируют. Впрочем, могу быть и неправ.